# can not parse EMV TAG ssuer Application DATA 0FA5

Tags: tags, token, iso, emv

I have this Issuer Application Data I need to parse :
0FA501A23030100000000000000000000F010000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is rarely the case somebody needs to ask about parsing IAD.

On the acquiring side it is considered issuer discretionary. It just passes through - you don't need to parse it.

On the issuing side, you should have the documentation as you know what card application is running there and it should be quite obvious for you what is there.

I'm afraid the answer is that you should look at the documentation for your card application.